# SQL, for result set, get first related row and then first related row again

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following model structure.

```
class prisoner(models.model):
    pass

class arrest(models.model):
    prisoner = models.ForeignKey('prisoner')
    ...
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('arrest_year', 'arrest_month', 'arrest_day')

class detention(models.model):
    arrest = models.ForeignKey('prisoner')
    notes = models.ManyToManyField('Notes')
    ...
    class Meta:
        order_by('-detention_year', '-detention_month', '-detention_day')
```

Each prisoner can have multiple arrests and detentions.

I would like to get the first arrest instance, then the first detention attached to this arrest.  Ideally i'd have a query which gives me a record set of these detention objects (the first detention obj attached to first arrest), each one annoted with the corresponding prisoner id.

Unfortunately this is way beyond my SQL comprehension and I have no idea where to start with it.  How can this be done please?

Comment: Do you have your SQL table structure, and some data ready to share?

Comment: This is neither SQL nor PostgreSQL. What framework are you working with?